# Typecasting in c++

Tags: c++, casting

```
void func::open()
{
 RequestSession* psg = new RequestSession;
((RequestSession*)psg)->st.ProVer = PRO_VERSION; //PRO_VERSION is macro
((RequestSession*)psg)->st.DevID  = DEVICE_ID; //DEVICE_ID is macro
}
```

I could not understand what is the need for type casting once again as psg is the pointer of RequestSession class.

Comment: Not sure about the exact case, but it could have been cast into some other type, but this casting is kept for further clarifying.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be very clarifying, does it?:-)

Comment: You also have a memory leak in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply, whenever you see a C-style cast in C++ code, it is wrong. For the very, very rare occasions when a cast is needed, you should be using `static_cast`, or even more rarely `reinterpret_cast`. The only cast that appears at all in my own code is `dynamic_cast`, which is needed when you really need to find the type of something, but this too is quite rare.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need of typecasting here. It's redundant and removable.